# Metric connectedNativeClientsByUser missing from Cassandra 3.11.13

Tags: cassandra

**cassandra version: 3.11.13**

I want to build dashboard with - info how many every user have connection. Based on document there is metric - `org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Client.connectedNativeClientsByUser`. But when I check it with `jconsole`, I don't see it
[image: jconsole]

Does I miss something in config or this is just outdated documentation?
Does it possible to have `connectedNativeClientsByUser` in 3.11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a documentation bug, the 3.11 code does not have the metric connectedNativeClientsByUser within it, but 4.0 onwards does - it was added by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13665.

I have added a ticket : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-18689 to fix the docs and a PR is in for review of the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to the [Monitoring](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/operating/metrics.html) page on the official Apache Cassandra website. If so, unfortunately it's incorrect.

The `connectedNativeClientsByUser` metric was [added in Cassandra 4.0](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0/CHANGES.txt#L910) ([CASSANDRA-14524](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14524)) and is not available in Cassandra 3.11 (which has reached end-of-life).

The metric was incorrectly added to the Monitoring page last year when the website was migrated to the Antora/AsciiDoc content management platform and some 4.0 documents were inadvertently merged to the 3.11 branch.

Thanks to [Andrew](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6526/andrew), the page will get corrected in [CASSANDRA-18689](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-18689). Cheers!